# Is It Possible To Attach / Unattach a has_one, through Association Using A Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-one

My models look like this:

```
class Photo


   has_one :photo_gallery
   has_one :gallery, through: :photo_gallery

end

class PhotoGallery

   belongs_to :photo
   belongs_to :gallery

end

class Gallery

   has_many :photo_galleries
   has_many :photos, through: :photo_galleries

end
```

For the purposed of this question, there is a single `Gallery` available from `Gallery.only_gallery`.

I would like the form for `Photo` to contain a checkbox.

If the checkbox is checked when the form is submitted, the Photo is associated with `Gallery.only_gallery` via a `PhotoGallery` model. If it is unchecked, this association is destroyed.

**Is this possible?**

I understand how to set up strong params to accept whatever is necessary. What I don't understand is how to create a form that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't modify associations via a form: they either exist or they don't.

In your case, if you don't check the check-box no row will be created in the join table for the two models so you shouldn't have a problem.

I would recommend something like this in your form photo:

```
<%= f.label :gallery_ids %> <br>
<%= collection_select(:photo, :gallery_ids, Gallery.all, :id, :name) %>
```

and add

```
dependent: :nullify
```

to your model associations

Comment: But surely this is for a `has_many` assocaition? And how does it remove the association when unchecked?

Comment: Take a look at my edit. Since you have a has_one you can just use a select box instead. And to remove the association you can add the nullify option to set the id to nil